# Symfony Form's button does not post data

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to post data through Symfony form's button but it does not validate form.

Here is my controller file:

```
public function PurchaseProductAction(Request $request)
    {
$defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
         $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
    ->setMethod('POST')
        ->add('CompanyName', 'text', array(
        'label'=>false    
    ))
    ->add('Address1', 'text', array(
        'label'=>false   
    ))
        ->add('Continue_to_Step_2', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) 
    {
        // It does not come here
        $data = $form->getData();
        $value = $data['CompanyName'];
            echo $value;
    }
}
```

Its my twig file:

`{% block content %}`

Company Name{{ form_row(form.CompanyName) }}


Address Line 1{{ form_row(form.Address1) }}




{{form_widget(form.Continue_to_Step_2)}}

{% endblock %}

Kindly guide me what I am doing wrong due to which my method does not call?

Comment: It's more likely that you forgot to wrap evething with `<form>`, right?

Comment: if I place form tag in twig then It click and validate missing fields but still does not call $form->handleRequest($request);

Comment: You are referring to HTML5 validation? @Ahmed Siouani explained in his answer what you need to do "by the book" :)

Comment: no I am simply talking about form validation check $form->isValid()) it does not call.

Comment: But, that doesn't make sense :) My first guess would be that you are missing `CSRF` token field - that is why `isValid()` is failing. Can you `die(print_r($form->getErrors(), TRUE));`?

Comment: it is showing Array ( ) invalid form

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `TRUE` as second argument to `print_r` call. I have edited the comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [Rendering a Form in a Template part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-a-form-in-a-template) of [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html), you've to include the `{{ form_start(form) }}` and the `{{ form_end(form) }}` twig form helpers.

This will generate the appropriate `<form>` tags according to your form definition.

Also, **keep in mind** that Support for submit buttons was added in **Symfony 2.3**. Before that, you had to add buttons to the form's HTML manually.

**Update,**

[form_end](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables) should be called with `render_rest` option set to `false` if you don't want it to show unrendered fields,

```
{# don't render unrendered fields #}
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

Comment: It added the whole form which is not needed here. I want to customise form fields manually in twig rather than load the complete form.

Comment: [form_start](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-start-view-variables) and [form_end](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables) don't show the whole form. they only show the start and the end <form> tags.

You can then customize your form fields manually between these two tags.

Comment: Agreed. @AliHassan What are you referring to is `form_widget(form)` statement.

Comment: {{ form_start(form) }}
<h1>Company Information</h1>
<table style="width:50%">
<tr>
<td style="width:50%">Company Name</td><td style="width:.1">{{ form_row(form.CompanyName) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:50%">Address Line 1</td><td style="width:.1">{{ form_row(form.Address1) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:50%">Address Line 2</td><td style="width:.1">{{ form_row(form.Address2) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
{{form_widget(form.Continue_to_Step_2)}}
</td>
</tr>
</table>

I added this and now my remaining fields are also shown on screen.:(

Comment: Hey, read the documentation of form_end I sent you !

{# don't render unrendered fields #}
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}

You've then to pass false to the render_rest option of form_end.

I updated my answer to make it clearer on this point :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Now it does not show extra fields but still shows invalid form console.

Comment: It only works fine If I write


{{ form(form) }}

in my twig file

Which I dont want :(